# Show a graph depicting the review progress over time

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, graphs

The new review tool is very well thought through and even catches "old stuff" which isn't acceptable judging from the quality demands that we expect today in SO.

I was just wondering if this is a Sisyphean task or if we can hope to melt that huge queue away. At any rate it would be interesting **how the size of the queue developed over time**.  For example, right now we have about 19k low quality posts and 62k close votes. Are these numbers shrinking? Are they increasing?

Comment: low quality posts are going down by several thousand most days, and adding *much* less.  My guess is that it'll be close to empty in the first week of September.  Suggested edits has been close to empty since like a day after it came out.  Close votes has been growing, not shrinking (since many of the review actions involve voting to close).  These graphs will start to get rather boring pretty soon.  It would be much more interesting if we could see graphs going back to before the new queue started.

Comment: @Servy: I would have guessed so (not that precisely, though). It's to be expected that the "close votes" queue starts shrinking after the "low quality" queue is empty. It would still be nice to have a graphic. :)

Comment: One of the problems with the vote to close is that you are limited to 50 votes per day, unlike LQP which isn't nearly as limited.  There are people who performed 1k-1.5k or more actions per day when it first came out (and there is always several over 500) which helps it go down quicker.  The suggested edits have more reviewers, so the limited number of reviews is...less limiting.

Comment: @Servy: Still, the 62k close queue could be eaten in 1240 person-days if everybody hits the VTC cap. Given that there are at least 100 people patrolling the review process, the queue could be gone in two weeks. Since this is obviously not the case, I'd assume the VTC limit is not a problem.

Comment: Any update on this? Can we get a graph?

Comment: It would be possible to use [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/), as was done in this absolutely great answer [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8575/178596).